# ConcatRelated Returning Multiple Values

Tags: ms-access, concatenation

I am new to MS Access and am trying to build a database that includes a text roll up (effectively summarising staff feedback collectively to the manager). I have set it up using ConcatRelated (http://allenbrowne.com/func-concat.html) and this works as expected. The only issue is that I cannot seem to ensure that only the first instance of a value is returned, rather than every instance. For example:

[image]

The function is bringing back the top view, but I only want it to bring back the Distinct values - please note, as this is a manager view, the same value can appear multiple times in the data retrieved. As such, I almost need the text to de-dupe if it is already there.

Full disclosure - my SQL is not great, so I am using the Expression Builder from the design view

Any help will be appreciated

EDIT for more detail:

The image shows a sample of the data and the output. In this, Mary is the team leader and so is responsible for the areas of John, Steven, Erin, and Harriet. The UID refers to the responsibility area.

As you can see, the dataset has the "minimum target" referenced against the area of responsibility and the output I am getting is duplicating the comments (which I presume is because the value is returned twice), but I am trying to ensure that commentary is summarised, not duplicated.

Note, in the summary output, I am not interested in the areas of responsibility, just the commentary against the staff names.

I hope that makes sense

Comment: Edit question to show sample raw data with real field and table names as well as desired output.

Comment: If the Area and UID are not relevant, don't include them in query. You show data summarized to each person as desired output.  I don't see how the additional information changes my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Build a query that retrieves distinct Comments values for each person:

`SELECT DISTINCT Person, Comments FROM table;`

or

`SELECT Person, Comments FROM table GROUP BY Person, Comments;`

Now reference that query in ConcatRelated function as source for Comments values.

Be aware that calling a function like this in query along with aggregating can cause slow performance with large dataset.

Comment: Thanks for that. I had a crack at that, but its not exactly working - I have unique values in the new query against each person, but when I try to summarise them at a higher level (and apologies for not putting this context in the initial question), for example a manager, it is bringing in the multiples still. Edited the question for clarity